# Пропустить кавычки и слеши

Tags: php, mysqli

Использую `mysqli` запрос `prepare` в вставляемом тексте, есть пути имеющие слеши `\` и слова например: `it's` как мне сказать `mysqli`, что это норма - жри?

```
if($exec = $db->prepare("INSERT into `my_t`(`id`, `autor`, `date`, `short_story`, `title`, `category`, `approve`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1)")) {
    $exec->bind_param(
        'issssi',
        $id,
        $autor,
        $dateTime,
        $short_story,
        $title,
        $id_category
    );
    $exec->execute();

}
```

Comment: Экранировать. 
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: у вас в таком виде что-то не работает, или в чем проблема?

Comment: @teran в итоге в БД пишеться например: С:Windowssystem32. Или или слово its.

Comment: не верю. Параметризованные запросы как раз и созданы для того, чтобы облегчить жизнь при передаче параметров и собственно передавать их СУБД на выполнение отдельно от самого запроса. Как вы заполняете сами параметры? что находится в переменных самих?

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не изменяет память все ковычки в тексте экранируются `\\\" текст \\\"`

Comment: Это не то, мне надо что бы в БД записало эти символы вместе с текстом.

Comment: ну вы на выходе и получите "текст"

Comment: У меня переменная где внутри 100500 слов, новостная статья, мне под каждый символ replace делать?

Comment: делайте экранирование кавычек с помощью PHP - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Функция `addslashes` решила мою проблему. `$short_story =addslashes($short_story);`

Comment: не слишком рекомендую пользоваться этой функцией. В mysqli и PDO есть специальные функции экранировки. Хотя очень странно, если вы используете подготовленные запросы, то экранировка должна происходить автоматически (при этом символы не вырезаются).